# Estimate of the Laplacian of a distance function on a Riemannian manifold with non-negative Ricci curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, laplacian

I'm reading the Petersen's book "Riemannian Geometry". My goal is to learn the proof of the Cheeger-Gromoll Splitting Theorem. It's quite complex and made by a lot of step. Now I'm trying to understand the proof of the Lemma 42 of section 3.3 (page 284).

The statement is:

> LEMMA: Let $r(x) = d(x,p)$, with $p \in (M,g)$. If $Ric \ge 0$, then
>   $$ \Delta r(x) \le \frac{n-1}{r(x)} \qquad \text{for all }x \in M.$$

The first sentence in the proof is "**We know that the result is true whenever $r$ is smooth.**"
Why? I can't see it.

Comment: I added a page reference. There are five different sections in Petersen's book labeled "Section 3.3."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Petersen is referring to Lemma 34 on page 268, where he proves a more general Laplacian estimate under arbitrary lower Ricci bounds. Although the statement of that lemma doesn't mention it, in the proof it's evident that he's assuming $r$ is smooth. Thus the point of Lemma 42 on page 284 is to extend that result to the more general case in which $r$ is merely Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much! I skipped the first two sections of the chapter because I'm just interested in the Splitting Theorem, but apparently it wasn't a wise choice.. :D